# Can running deer be described as "churning"?

Tags: meaning, word-request

I heard a movie description

> With the reindeer's **legs churning**, they fly directly toward the moon.

Can a galloping/running ungulate be described as "legs churning"? Or did I hear it wrong? I don't think it's **journeying** either, because a person journeys, not legs. I am putting the [audio clip here](https://clyp.it/ewakikhs) (uploaded to an audio sharing site Clyp) for reference.

Also what are other verbs that describe the legs of a galloping four-legged animal like shown in this pic?

[image]

Comment: One (somewhat figurative) definition of "churn" is *"to move (something) vigorously"*, so it works fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that [Merriam-Webster's definition of *churn*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/churn) includes in one entry:

> intransitive verb
>    1 : to work a churn (as in making butter)
>    2 a : to produce, proceed with, or experience violent motion or agitation · her stomach was *churning* · *churning* legs
>      b : to proceed by or as if by means of rotating members (such as wheels or propellers) · boats *churning* across the harbor

This was the first result in a Google search for `legs churning`; other results seem to show this phrase in common use particularly to refer to cyclists …

Answer (score 1):

Think about the leg motion of a four legged animal. Their legs move almost in a circular motion. Churning is a way to describe a circular motion. Certainly it can be used to describe the motion of an animals legs. I haven't personally heard that used, but it makes sense in the context.